# Unbalanced dyadic design (multilevel model)

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, multilevel-analysis, psychology, dyadic-data

I study the physiological linkage between patients and doctors. I have 100 patients and only 15 doctors. The aim of my research is to examine the physiological concordance between physician's heart rate variability and patient's heart rate variability in a follow-up consultation. So each of one hundred patients participates only once in the study and each of 15 physicians several times.

This physiological concordance should be also moderated by patient's perception of physician empathy and patient's acculturation degree (as we have patients from different origins).

I was told that the best option would be to use a multilevel model with heart rate variability data at Level 1 and subjects at Level2. How can I construct my model with such an unbalanced design?

Comment: At the moment you are asking quite a broad question. Perhaps you could browse some of the previous posts tagged multilevel-analysis and see what insight you can get from them and then come back with some narrower questions? Multi-level analysis does seem indicated here.